# What is the recommended way of removing a siliconed in tub jet tube

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, pump, hot-tub

I was trying to get our jetted tub back in operational order when I noticed it was leaking. After cutting a hole in the wall in the other room, I traced the leak back to a tube that was not properly sealed. The tubing used is some sort of soft but very stiff PVC tubing. It appears to have silicone calking or something similar all around holding it in. Ideally, I'd like to take it out and clean it up and put a better layer down, but I am finding it very hard to get it out. Are there any tricks to loosening or this up? Perhaps a tool made for sticking down inside the crack and cutting the silicone?

[image]

I've tried to cut with a hobby knife and pulled out as much as I could with needle nose pliers, but it still won't come out.

Answer (score 2):

That would not be silicone caulk. It is PVC glue. You can see the blue primer on part of the fitting. The PVC tubing would have been coated with PVC glue as would the interior of the fitting and the two of them twisted together. The tubing probably goes all the way into the fitting. It's almost impossible to get that apart without damaging it to the extent that you wouldn't be able to reglue it. When I've had repair jobs like that, I have replaced the fitting and added some extra PVC to connect to the PVC tubing.

Comment: Yes they are glued, I usually cut back a few inches so a coupler can be added, the pipe has some flex but not much and since it has been heat cycled can sometimes cause leaks at other jets so try to be gentle with the part you don’t need to replace.